# Create Nuget Package with binary Content Files - is this possible?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, nuget-spec

I try to create a nuget package with a binary file in the contentFiles folder.

Unfortunately when I try to restore I get an error message saying the file is a binary file not ascii text.

Is there some way to add binary files to the ContentFiles folder of a NugetPackage that correctly restores?

Comment: Did you find a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible. Did you make sure to force the build action to none (the default is compile)?

```
<contentFiles>
    <files include="**/*.*" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />
</contentFiles>
```